# Запрет пользователем сайта доступа к файлам .php .js и т.д. по адресу

Tags: php, веб-сайт, chmod, права-доступа

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. На сайте есть форма, обрабатывается с помощью файла mail.php
При переходе по адресу //:сайт/code/mail.php происходит отправка пустой формы.

UPD:
**Возможно решения для кого-то**
Не добавил для проверки

```
isset($_POST['submit']
```

Но остался вопрос. Как запретить доступ на просмотр файлов .js и т.д. пользователям по прямому адресу?

Comment: Не легче делать проверку на то, является ли форма пустая, и если является, то не выполнять дальнейший код?

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer конечно же нет) Лучше каких-нибудь костылей навставляем, чтоб потом нихрена не понятно было)

Comment: Для этого обычно выдаются токен или cookie, которые намекают на то, чтобы обратиться с файлу mail.php нужно сначала получить этот токен от сервера в HTML на другой странице. mail.php затем делает проверку на выданный токен, и обрабатывает запрос. Что-то вроде CSRF механизма.

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer Спасибо. Совсем забыл) Может еще знаете "Как запретить доступ на просмотр файлов .js и т.д. пользователям по прямому адресу?"

Comment: @Skilsar, возможно костыль, но, как вариант, сделать php скрипт, который будет проверять, кто делает запрос на адрес и затем уже выдавать JS через echo или редиректом

Comment: js файл подключается свободно через <script? ЧТОБЫ н сработал и его конечно любой может просмотреть.. а если ему для этого надо будет POST-запрос организовать, то ОН НЕ ПОДКЛЮЧИТСЯ и не сработает.. что-это за необходимость так прятать js файлы.. проще их в ZIP упаковать с паролем и сообщать пароль только тем кому разрешено.. типа если продаешь js-код =))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для проверки кто обращается к mail.php, можно использовать проверку:

```
isset($_POST['submit'];
```

На счёт запрета просмотра JS файлов, можно сделать небольшой скрипт на php который будет проверять, кто к нему обращается и взависимости от результата делать редирект на JS файл или выводить Js через **echo**.

Как пример, когда нужно будет дёрнуть js скрипт, можно будет, скажем, к **handler.php**, обращаться с POST запросом в теле корого укзаывать что то типо такого: **act=secretJs**, в свою очередь  в **handler.php** будет что то типо такого:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['act'] == "secretJs"){
    echo '<script> alert("hello world"); </script>';
}
?>
```